# MATLAB string to integer conversion

Tags: string, matlab

I am a newbie at matlab. I have deployed a machine learning model(developed using python) using flask. From matlab, I have called the API and received a string response. The response is like: '[0.8]'. but matlab is showing the size of the string is 1. I need only the value 0.8. My code:

```
import matlab.net.http.*
import matlab.net.http.field.*

request = RequestMessage( 'POST', ...
    [ContentTypeField( 'application/vnd.api+json' ), AcceptField('application/vnd.api+json')], ...
    '{"meta": {"Speed_RPM_PU": 0.2}}' );
response = request.send( 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/predict' );
ans=response.Body.Data
length(ans) % equals to 1
% for i = 1:length(ans)
%  
%    fprintf('%c ',ans(i))
%  
%    %disp(String(i))
%  
% end
```

Here, ans='[0.8]'

Comment: Call `str2double` after removing the brackets by indexing. Maybe `str2double(ans(2:end-1))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ans='[0.8]'` then `length(ans)` would be equal to 5 (because there are 5 characters in this char array). I suspect that you actually have `ans={'[0.8]'}`, i.e. a cell array of length 1 which contains a single char array. Otherwise you are using single quotation marks `'_'` which indicate a *char* where MATLAB is actually showing double quotation marks `"_"` which indicate a *string*, since the length would be 1 if it was a string too. Chars and strings are not equivalent.

Calling `class(ans)` instead of `length(ans)` would tell you which of these is correct.

You can use `str2num(ans)` in any case, but if it's a cell you'll need `str2num(ans{1})`

```
str2num('[0.8]') % = 0.8 (double from char)
str2num("[0.8]") % = 0.8 (double from string)

str2num({'0.8'}) % -> error
a = {'0.8'};
str2num(a{1})    % = 0.8 (double from char element of cell)
```

`str2double` is often preferred over `str2num`, but you would need to remove the square brackets from your char/string or it would give NaN, so something like

```
str2double( erase( '[0.8]', {'[',']'} ) ) % = 0.8 (double)
```

Note that `ans` is the default variable name for unassigned function outputs, consider using a different variable name to avoid unexpected issues.